# How to edit array value if value does not exist

Tags: arrays, wordpress

I am trying to query states based on location by state. Example of address strings that come from map_location meta key:

- BATEMANS BAY NSW 2536 Australia
- BATEMANS BAY NEW SOUTH WALES 2536 Australia

I cant work out how to have the 'map_location' value = ' NSW ' or 'NEW SOUTH WALES'

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'listing_status',
            'value' => 'current'
        ),
       array(
            'key' => 'map_location',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'value' => 'NSW'
       )
    )
);

$state_posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:--

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
       array(
            'key' => 'listing_status',
            'value' => 'current'
       ),
       array(
            'key' => 'map_location',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'value' => 'NSW'
       ),
       array(
            'key' => 'map_location',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'value' => 'NEW SOUTH WALES'
       )
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks - but that does not work.. it returns no results. I came across this 
http://www.themesandco.com/snippet/three-techniques-to-alter-the-query-in-wordpress/

but I am not quite sure if this is what I need, I am having trouble implementing it. Any pointers will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In this case problem is partial match, do in two steps: find right posts and then query them. Try this (tested) solution, after edit with pagination (again would be easier on second query, but will reduce performance):

```
$meta_key1 = 'map_location';
$meta_value1 = '%NSW%';
$meta_key2 = 'map_location';
$meta_value2 = '%NEW SOUTH WALES%';
$meta_key3 = 'listing_status';
$meta_value3 = 'current';
if (get_query_var('paged')) $page_no = get_query_var( 'paged' ) - 1; else $page_no = 0;
$posts_per_page = 1;

global $wpdb;
$postids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( 
  "
  SELECT      key2.post_id
  FROM        $wpdb->postmeta key2
  INNER JOIN  $wpdb->postmeta key1 
          ON key1.post_id = key2.post_id
          AND ((key1.meta_key = %s AND key1.meta_value LIKE %s) OR (key1.meta_key = %s AND key1.meta_value LIKE %s))
  WHERE       key2.meta_key = %s AND key2.meta_value = %s LIMIT %d , %d
",
$meta_key1,
$meta_value1,
$meta_key2,
$meta_value2,
$meta_key3, 
$meta_value3,
$page_no,
$posts_per_page
) ); 

$the_query = new WP_Query( array('post__in' => $postids ) );
```

BTW, without partial match solution is much simpler:

```
$args = array(
'meta_query' => array(
  array(
  'key' => 'listing_status',
  'value' => 'current',
  'meta_compare' => '='
   ),
  array(
  'key' => 'map_location',
  'value' => array('NEW SOUTH WALES','BATEMANS BAY NEW SOUTH WALES 2536 Australia'),
  'meta_compare' => 'IN'
   )
 )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Michal, **you are a legend!!** it seems to work very well!

I am now wondering what method do I need to use to get WordPress pagination to work..

Comment: Glad I could help :), now I'm my way, will add pagination to my solut. later today.

Comment: :)))) cant wait to see how you do it!!

Comment: I have come across a problem, if I try it for another state:

`$meta_value1 = '%WA%';'

'$meta_value2 = '%WESTERN AUSTRALIA%';'`

'WA' will return results from NEW SOUTH WALES, because of 'WAles' .. hmmm

Comment: pagination is added above. simple answer to problem with WA match, '% WA %', but to be more sophisticated you need regexp match. - can you list more samples?

Comment: Hi mate, thanks very much.

Other use cases are:

WA / Western Australia, NSW / New South Wales, SA /South Australia, NT / Northern Territory, VIC / Victoria, TAS / Tasmania, ACT /Australian Capital Territory.

It need to search string ACT or Australian Capital Territory.
WA or Western Australia etc...they will be separate pages

mysite.com/state/western-australia
mysite.com/state/new-south-wales


Does this make sense?